# Send text/email from portable desktop java application

Tags: java, email, text, usb

This question is more of like a requirement feasibility study.
Requirement: I have a java based portable(USB)application. I need to add a feature where the user can send text/email from this application.

I know that someone, who can plugin the application via USB , can open up the browser and send an email. Fairly simple. However, if I want that the user need not open the browser and send a text/email, is that possible ?

I know how to send email (using Java Mail API) from a Java Servlet. I want to achieve the same from this portable java application.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What is a "java based USB application" ?  Are you using USB to mean something other than "Universal Serial Bus"?  Or if that, please explain the role of that interface to your application.

Comment: Hello Chris, I am not using USB to mean something other than Universal Serial Bus.

Comment: @Margi You can create a standalone application using java swing. You will need a SMTP server or some sorta mail server to connect to. Maybe the requirement is that each of these portable machines have a mail server configured and have an internet connection as well.

Comment: Thanks Khush.I tried using Java Mail API and it works well.Used smtp.gmail.com as my smtp host.So, my requirement is sastified. I have to similarly send text sms from my java desktop application.How can I do that?